# Exact Keyword Match for Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have been all over SO and found many different possible solutions. I feel like there is something very easy that I am overlooking. My script on key markup filters `<li>` but my problem is the script will return any `<li>` matching the individual characters. I need the search function to return word matches not character matches.

```
function search() {
    var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
    li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
        txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
        if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help. Stay classy SO. Here is my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkwaak/vstuym40/)

Comment: You can split string that a.textContent, which will return array for strings(words) and then you can use includes method to check if the string contains the word or not

Comment: please add your html codes. But in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s912khcj/), it seems your search function works as you expect.

Comment: I would recommend using String.match() and regex if you are trying to look for an exact match to a string.

Comment: @Sphinx I updated the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jkwaak/vstuym40/) with my html. Can you look at it and see what i need to change? thanks.

Comment: Ok, the fiddle works perfectly, but for some reason it doesn't with my application. [my website](https://guardian-search.web.app/) doesn't respond correctly. Any thoughts?

Comment: Most probably caused by there are two functions named 'search'

Comment: @Sphinx sorry - I commented out the first function and it still doesn't work. I added more html to the fiddle. By doing this I realized that the function isn't actually working.

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi can you take a look at the fiddle I posted and show me how you would change the function to work please?

Comment: @MartinBalke I have seen a lot of solutions using regex, but I am really not familiar with it and I get lost with the syntax. If you could look at the fiddle too and give me an idea I would appreciate that.

Comment: @JackK. I didn't see you post out new fiddle, the fiddle in four comment is working fine. Anyway, if the fiddle in four comment meets your requirements, that means there are something else wrong in your codes. It doesn't matter you use either `String.match` or `String.indexOf`.

Comment: I fixed it. Apparently, the script was trying to filter a nested `<ol>` within the `<ul>`. I didn't need it so I just deleted the nested one and it works like a charm. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and put together some code that accomplishes what you want. Reg is a new  instance of Regex that checks to see if your word "filter" is present. \b here stands for word boundary. It also has the added affect of searching insensitive to case so you can clean up some of your normalization of strings with toUpperCase() calls. I hope this helps

```
function search() {
var input, filter, ul, li, a, i, txtValue;
input = document.getElementById("myInput");
filter = input.value;
ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");
let reg = new RegExp(`\\b${filter}\\b`, 'gi');
for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
    a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
    txtValue = a.textContent || a.innerText;
    if (txtValue.match(reg)) {
        li[i].style.display = "";
    } else {
        li[i].style.display = "none";
    }
 } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for you time. Sorry to have wasted it. I figured it out. Apparently the function gets lost if there's a nested `<ol>` within the `<ul>`.

Answer (score 0):

I had a nested `<ol>` within a `<ul>` which was confusing the function. I deleted the nested one and it works like a charm.